# Ruby hash to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby, hash

I have a Ruby hash which is passed to a hidden field. How do I extract this hash into JavaScript arrays that I can work with? I need to access the key/value pairs in JavaScript.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `my_awesome_ruby_hash.to_json` and then you can simply either `eval` it in js or use `parseJSON`. You might need to `require 'json'` (not in Rails).

Comment: thanks, that works. how would i iterate through the result in the js code? i.e. the key/value pairs...does json return a js hash?

Comment: `{ "a" => [1,2,3] }` will turn into `{ "a" : [1,2,3]}` so you can do `obj["a"]` in js to get it or a `for in` loop.

Comment: @jakub Hampl - i have this:  myList = Hash.new()
              myList[var1] = const1
              myList[var2] = const2
I set a variable in my controller as follows: @myHash = myList.to_json
In my javascript, I get the value as follows:                     theList = JSON.parse($('#hiddenfield').attr('value'));
for (key in theList) {
  alert("key "+key);
  alert(theList[key]);
  alert(theList[thelist(key)]);
 }
Alert1 is "key0", Alert2 is "var1", Alert3 is "undefined". I can't seem to access the value per key. Any suggestions?

Comment: `for (key in object) {
  if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  value = object[key];
}` should do the trick.

Comment: it still doesn't work, just returns the index e.g. 0 and the var1 as above

Comment: ok, sorry, it does work. i had a sort on the hash.keys which was interfering with things. is it possible to sort the hash? also, why does the code above work?what does the hasOwnProperty do?

Comment: Try http://www.google.com/search?q=hasOwnProperty ;) It excludes stuff that objects inherit in js. A workaround for unusual behaviour in javascript.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl how do i sort before converting to json? if i go hash.sort.to_json the iteration doesn't work, if i convert to_a and then sort it doesn't work either....

Comment: Update the question with the code and expected data you're using.

Comment: something like this:  myList = Hash.new() myList["a"] = "a" myList["b"] = "b" The hiddenfield is set: #myList is set to myList.sort.to_json ....in javascript: var myList = JSON.parse($('#myList').attr('value'));
    for (key in myList) {
     var value = myList[key];
     alert(value); alert(key);
    } The result is that key and value are not showing the keys and values, just the keys....by sorting it seems to be messing up the parsed json, all i want to do is get a sorted hash either in the javascript once the json is parsed or before converting to json and passing to javascript

Comment: Ruby sort transforms a hash into an array so `{"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b"}.sort` => `[["a", "a"], ["b", "b"]]`. Also in JS hashes are not sortable i.e., their ordering is not defined. But that is a different topic and there's a lot of resources online for that or you can ask a new question on this site.

Answer (score 30):

Ruby code:

```
state = { 'Waiting' => { name: 'Waiting now', color: 'btn-default' },
'Trying' => { name: 'Trying now', color: 'btn-danger' },
'Answered' => { name: 'Answered now', color: 'btn-success' } }
```

javascript code:

```
var state = JSON.parse('#{raw(state.to_json)}');
```

Comment: Note, the single quotes are important because the to_json method creates a JSON string with embedded double quotes. Here is the form I used in my situation, where the javascript was in an embedded Ruby file (filename.html.erb): `var data = JSON.parse('<%= raw(@contacts_list.to_json) %>');`